# Mbed Simple C Calculator

Tags: c, calculator, mbed, keypad

I have created a code to implement a keypad on an Mbed microcontroller. The code checks the entered pin versus the correct pin.

Now, I need some help for converting this code into a simple calculator. I do not know how to convert the character array into a string to return integer values. I want to be able to enter number one, choose an operation, enter number 2, and compute. ex: 10+21= 31

I would like to be able to assign the operations (+,-,/,*) to keys 1-4. Any help would be appreciated!

edit: I have tried using 'value= atoi(str)' with no luck. Would initially creating a integer array instead of a character array be more beneficial?

```
#include "mbed.h"

DigitalOut led2(LED2);
DigitalOut led1(LED1);               // Declare LED
DigitalOut rows [4]= {PA_5, PA_1, PA_2, PA_3};       // Declare Rows
DigitalIn columns [3]= {PB_6, PB_7, PD_0};           // Declare Columns
char numpad [4] [3]= {
    {'1', '2', '3'},
    {'4', '5', '6'},
    {'7', '8', '9'},
    {'*', '0', '#'},
};
int c= 0;

int main (){
    char detected [6] = " ";
    char strCheck[]   = "3333#"; 
    led2 = 1;

    columns [0]. mode (PullUp);
    columns [1]. mode (PullUp);
    columns [2]. mode (PullUp);
    char read; 

    while (1){
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
            rows[0]= 1; 
            rows[1]= 1;
            rows[2]= 1; 
            rows[3]= 1;
            rows[i]= 0;
            wait (0.01);
            for (int j= 0; j<3; j++) {
                if (columns [j]== 0) {
                    read= numpad [i][j];
                    printf("%c \n\r", read);
                    detected [c]= numpad [i][j];
                    detected [c+1]= '\0';
                    printf("%s \n\r", detected);
                    c++;
                         if (c==5) {
                         c= 0;
                    }
                    wait (0.005);
                    while (columns [j]== 0);
                }
            }
        }
        if (strcmp (detected, strCheck)== 0){
            led1 = 1;
            led2 = 0;
            printf ("%s \n\r", detected);
            c = 0;
            detected[0]= '\0';
        }
        else if (read== '*') { 
            led1 = 0;
            led2 = 1;
            c = 0;
            detected [0] = '\0';
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Read more about [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) & [lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis), notably about [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) & [LL parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser). However, StackOverflow is not a do-my-work site. Notice that the `bison` parser generator has an [infix calculator example](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Infix-Calc.html)

Comment: (as a response to a deleted comment) But you are expected, as a student, to seek information and knowledge by yourself. So follow the links I gave you (not on your *free* time, but on your *homework* time). Also read carefully the documentation of [standard IO function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) and of *every* function that you are using.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch this is for a class of mine, and we havent necessarily covered those topics yet. I will definitely check them out in my free time though. I'm not necessarily looking for the code given to me. I just can not figure out how to convert the char array to return integer values. I used the function 'value= atoi(str)' and only got zeros in my terminal.

Comment: Read also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It could be simpler to first write a program running on PC (e.g. using the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler) and then port it to your embedded hardware. BTW, I recommend installing a [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) on your PC, since they are *very* student and developer friendly

Comment: @Dafrankster Instead Mbed code.. edit your question with what you trying and explain/ask what issue or error you getting.. So that anyone will help you

Comment: So my suggestion might be to first write a simple calculator program on your Linux PC (since the [GDB debugging](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) facilities are very good), and later to port that to your embedded platform (where debugging might be harder)

Comment: Refer this [link](https://www.includehelp.com/c-programs/calculator-using-switch.aspx)